# How can I get a fully-qualified URL when using Postman environments?

Tags: postman

I have a RESTful application in which resources link to other resources via relative URIs. Say I have a resource `orders/57` that contains the following:

```
    "customer": "persons/123"
```

When I do an explicit `GET http://myapp-dev.example.com/orders/57`, the Postman client enhances the response body so that I can click on the `"persons/123"` and a new Postman tab will open with `GET http://myapp-dev.example.com/persons/123`.

This is great and super handy. BUT now I am using environments, so my original request becomes: `GET http://{{url}}/orders/57`, and when I click on the link to `"persons/123"`, the URL in the new tab is `http://{{url}}/persons/123`, it is parametrized instead of being fully-qualified.

That's really useful in a lot of cases, but in my case I am wanting to retrieve absolute URLs to include in task-management tickets so they can be QAed.

Is there any way I can get the absolute URL automagically using Postman? Or do I just have to deal and do the edits myself (not a huge problem but not ideal either).

Thanks!